# I met some strange errors when I practiced in LeetCode

Tags: c++

I try to use stack to implement queues,[Description](https://leetcode.com/problems/implement-queue-using-stacks/description/).
My solution is below:

```
class MyQueue {
public:
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    stack<int> my_stack;
    MyQueue() {

    }

    /** Push element x to the back of queue. */
    void push(int x) {
        stack<int> my_new_stack;
        my_new_stack.push(x);
        for(int i = 0; i < my_stack.size();i++){
            my_new_stack.push(my_stack.top());
            my_stack.pop();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i< my_new_stack.size();i++){
            my_stack.push(my_new_stack.top());
            my_new_stack.pop();
        }
    }

    /** Removes the element from in front of queue and returns that element. */
    int pop() {  // what about queue is empty
        int temp = my_stack.top(); 
        my_stack.pop();
        return temp;
    }

    /** Get the front element. */
    int peek() {
        return my_stack.top();
    }

    /** Returns whether the queue is empty. */
    bool empty() {
        return my_stack.empty();
;
    }


};

/**
 * Your MyQueue object will be instantiated and called as such:
 * MyQueue obj = new MyQueue();
 * obj.push(x);
 * int param_2 = obj.pop();
 * int param_3 = obj.peek();
 * bool param_4 = obj.empty();
 */
```

My test case is

`["MyQueue","empty","push","push","push","pop","pop","pop"]`
`[[],[],[1],[2],[3],[],[],[]]`

while the result is 
`[null,true,null,null,null,1,0,80]`
The true result is 
`[null,true,null,null,null,1,2,3]`

I know it is awkward in efficiency, but I really have no idea where the `0` and `80` from.

Thank you for kind help！

Comment: I suggest you take some time to read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and learn how to use a debugger. And if you want our help then I suggest you [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look very carefully at this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < my_stack.size();i++){
    my_new_stack.push(my_stack.top());
    my_stack.pop();
}
```

and think to yourself: What is the result of my `i < my_stack.size()` condition each time through the loop. Hint: it's not always the original size of the stack.

You would be far better off transferring from `my_stack` to `my_new_stack` as long as `my_stack` wasn't ***empty!***

And, yes, that word is emphasised for a reason, nudge nudge wink wink :-)

---

I'd also like to point out that you could make this scheme a little more efficient. You maintain the stack in a state where it's primed for extraction always. But think of what will happen if you insert a thousand items before extracting any.

That's *two thousand* reversals of all the items on the stack.

Far better would be to store the current mode (insert or extract) and only reverse when you need to.

For example, see the following pseudo-code:

```
def init():
    # Initialise in insert mode.

    stack = []
    mode = mode_insert

def reverseStack():
    # Transfer all items to get reverse order.

    newStack = []
    while not stack.empty():
        newStack.push(stack.top())
        stack.pop()

    # Use reversed stack now.

    stack = newStack

    # Change mode.

    if mode == mode_insert:
        mode = mode_extract
    else mode = mode_insert

def insert(item):
    # Put stack in right state and add the item.

    if mode == mode_extract:
        reverseStack()
    stack.push(item)

def extract():
    # Put stack in right state then get item out.

    if mode == mode_insert:
        reverseStack()
    item = stack.top()
    stack.pop()
    return item
```

This will actually be *substantially* more efficient if you have long runs of similar operations and marginally less efficient if you're alternating between insertion and extraction.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think I have gotten point. The size of `my_stack` is change in every loop! And the optimization is also good idea.

Answer (score 1):

at first,there is a logic error in your push method,you should make sure that the new int value should be pushed at the bottom of my_stack(after your exchanging).

secondly, in function for , stack.size() is not an invariant , it always changes and you use i++ at same time,so you lost some elements. I prefer while.

I am not good at english and hope you can undersand me.